# How can I access files outside of my webroot when using Vagrant?

Tags: drupal, vagrant, virtual-machine, hostname

I have a directory that contains the following structure:

```
phpinfo.php
adminer.php
drupal/
Vagrantfile
bootstrap.sh (config file)
index.html (on-boarding information for site-builder, etc.)
```

My synced folder is `drupal` (mapped to /var/www/html), but I also want to access `phpinfo.php` and `adminer.php`.

A hostname is also setup to be built as a webapp.dev host mapped to this new vagrant guest.

I could make the overall directory the synced folder, but I don't want to create clutter or have to access the site at webapp.dev/drupal.

How can I access both the drupal site as web root but still run the various tools? Is it possible to create an additional virtual host and synced directory that maps to the containing folder structure?

Comment: @curtisblackwell. Would you please restore the original question. The intent has changed enough that the question may not be specific to another user searching for it or trying to relate. Please also add the drupal/drupal7 tags. They were added on purpose to help developers working with drupal to find solutions that at this point are often outdated or do not apply directly.

Comment: I removed the Drupal-specific stuff and simplified the question because it was irrelevant to the issue. Others may see Drupal and keep looking because they'd think this doesn't apply when it actually does. If you still think the Drupal stuff should be in there, you should be able to edit. My edits would need approval just like yours (and I disagree that it should be in there in the first place).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can configure another synced folder. I'm doing this for certs that should be kept above webroot. Here's an excerpt from my Vagrantfile.

```
config.vm.synced_folder "./public_html", "/vagrant",
  id:            "vagrant-root",
  owner:         "vagrant",
  group:         "www-data",
  mount_options: ["dmode=775,fmode=664"]

config.vm.synced_folder "./certs", "/certs",
  id:            "certs"
```

Note you have to use a separate `id` for each folder.